# Click inside iframe, embed or object does not work on safari

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, object, iframe

I am pulling a 3rd party bookings system on a WordPress page. I used iFrame initially and it works fine on chrome browser and on Android phones, but it doesn't work on Safari (iPhone as well as mac). I tried  as well as

This is what I currently have on my page:

```
<div><object style="overflow: auto!important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;" data="https://www.ultimoht.net.au/webappointment/PatientDetails.aspx?DentalOfficeID=3614545" type="text/html" width="100%" height="800px">    </object></div>
```

The problem with safari is, it won't let user select a date on the page. May be the problem is the touch event.

When I open data link directly on the safari browser it works fine, it only causes an issue when it is inside an iframe or embed or object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it works for me on both my mac and iPhone with no problem running Safari 12 on mac. The first time it took a few clicks on mobile but it is working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nico, It does clicks after few mins. A user won't stay on the page for long hence the issue. It is smooth on chrome.